# Mahalanobis distance between two vectors

Tags: matlab, image-processing, statistics

I tried to apply [`mahal`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/mahal.html) to calculate the [Mahalanobis distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance) between 2 row-vectors of 27 variables, *i.e* `mahal(X, Y)`, where `X` and `Y` are the two vectors. However, it comes up with an error:

> `The number of rows of X must exceed the number of columns.`

After a few minutes of research I got that I can't use it like this, but I'm still not sure sure why. Can some explain it to me?

Also I have below an example of `mahal` method :

```
>> mahal([1.55 5 32],[5.76 43 34; 6.7 32 5; 3 3 5; 34 12 6;])

ans =    
   11.1706
```

Can someone clarify how MATLAB calculate the answer in this case?

**Edit:**
I found this code that calculate the mahalanobis distance:

```
S = cov(X);
mu = mean(X);
d = (Y-mu)*inv(S)*(Y-mu)'
d = ((Y-mu)/S)*(Y-mu)'; % <-- Mathworks prefers this way
```

I tested it on `[1.55 5 32]`, and `[5.76 43 34; 6.7 32 5; 3 3 5; 34 12 6;]` and it gave me the same result as if I used the `mahal` function (11.1706), and I tried to calculate the distance between the 2 vectors of 27 variables and it works. What do you think about it? Can I count on this solution since the `mahal` function can't do what I need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `mahal(X,Y)`... gave me this error:
>   `"The number of rows of X must exceed the number of columns."`

The [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/mahal.html) states that `Y` must have more rows than columns (also note that the documentation denotes `X` as the second input parameter, not the first). For you this  means that the *second array* that you're feeding into `mahal` has more rows than columns.

Why is that so important? The purpose of this restriction is make sure that `mahal` has enough data to build the correlation matrix used in the computation of the Mahalanobis distance. If there's not enough information, the output would be garbage.

In your case your input arrays are two input vectors, each having 27 elements. Are the 27 elements correspond to different observations, or are they one observation of 27 variables? If it's the former, just make sure both vectors are column vectors:

```
mahal(X(:), Y(:))
```

and you're good to go. If each vector contains only one observation, your estimation of the covariance matrix will be entirely inaccurate. Again, the rows of the inputs should be the observations!

> Can someone clarify how MATLAB calculated the answer in this case?

The [Mahalanobis distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance) between two vectors **x** and **y** is: `dM(x, y) = sqrt((x-y)TS-1(x-y))`, where **S** is their covariance matrix.

In MATLAB<sup>1</sup> `mahal(Y,X)` is efficiently implemented in the following manner:

```
m = mean(X,1);
M = m(ones(ry,1),:);
C = X - m(ones(rx,1),:);
[Q,R] = qr(C,0);

ri = R'\(Y-M)';
d = sum(ri.*ri,1)'*(rx-1);
```

You can verify that with:

```
type mahal
```

Note that MATLAB calculates the Mahalanobis distance in **squared units**, so in your example the Mahalanobis distance is actually the square root of 11.1706, *i.e* 3.3422.

> Can I count on this [my] solution since the `mahal` function can't do what I need?

You're doing everything correctly, so it's safe to use. Having said that, note that MATLAB did restrict the dimensions of the second input array for a good reason (stated above).

If `X` contains only one row, `cov` automatically converts it to a column vector, which means that each value will be treated as a different observation. The resulting `S` would be inaccurate (if not garbage).

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Checked for MATLAB release version R2007b.</sup>

Comment: @Maystro Please see the revised answer.

Comment: So what I'm doing is not accurate and does not give me the distance that I can count on it if I need to use it in any clustering algo., is that accurate?

Comment: @Maystro Yes, you got that right. You just need to decide if the 27 elements in each vector are _different_ observations or one observation of 27 variables. If you have 27 different observations, make sure that they are in different rows (_i.e_, the input is a column vector), and then you can use `mahal`. For your convenience, I've added this explanation to the answer.

Comment: @Etin, Actually the 27 elements represent one observation and I need to know the distance between each 2 observation, do you any alternative distance I can use to do the clustering?

Comment: @Maystro That really depends on the properties of your data set and observations (you may want to ask about that on [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com)...)

Comment: Hi, could you comment on - http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/232943-computing-mahalanobis-distance-between-set-of-points-and-set-of-reference-points? Thank You.

Comment: @Drazick It is better to ask this as a separate question to avoid cluttering the comment section for this answer, and also to allow other members of the SO community to see the question and share their thoughts.